# Catalyst controller to generate dymanic images and pass it to view/front end - Whats the best way?

Tags: catalyst

So questions is:

1. This is reporting application making use of Catalyst frameworks
2. In Controllers, I generate QR code images and want to pass this URL (of generated image)
   to specific view/front end? Note: I do not want to pass binary or base64 data from
   controller to view?
3. What should I stash in $c->stash->{Images} = ????

Any idea, hints ? Please guide...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I bypass the View entirely, and set the content-type and body to return an image directly from a controller in situations like this. Writing the image out to a file just so another call to the server can retrieve it seems neither sensible nor scalable. Ultimately, unless you're doing something very unorthodox, you'll be requesting the image from a page using `<img src="..."/>` anyway.

```
package SomeController;
...
sub qrcode :Local {
    my ($self, $c, @args) = @_;
    my $png;
    eval { $png = ... } } ||
        $c->res->redirect($c->uri_for('/static/images/sorry_qrcode_failed.png'));
    $c->res->content_type('image/png');
    $c->res->body($png);
}
```

... and your page requests

```
<img src="/somecontroller/qrcode/foo/bar" />
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: RET: Thank you !! Yes, This will work (This was my first solution). Infact, since these images can be thousands, so I saved them in /tmp and symlinks in static/images directory and src=<path_to_symlinks>. But my issue, is all static contents are served and cached when web server starts, so that way, during actual rendering, controllers wont be called for image generation, hence the dilemma, on how to do this?

Comment: So are you saying all possible QR Codes are already generated? In that case all you need to do is write some deterministic algorithm to convert @args to <filename>, and stash the results of that in `$c->stash->{qr_code}`. Your template (assuming TT) would have something like `<img src="/static/images/qr_codes/[% qr_code %].png"/>` in it.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: I do not want to pass binary or base64 data from controller to view?

Is this a question or a statement, I am not sure. I'd pass information to generate QR to the View, and the View would generate the actual image.

If you don't want to generate QR via View, nor pass any binary data, then there is only 1 option left: URL (http or file).

Comment: Moltar - thats my question, How would controller set the url for image and return to view. My all attempt to make it work failed. Any code sample will help? I can share part of the code samples..via email..

Comment: Maybe you should provide some code, as your question isn't very clear. You can pass the URL via stash easily, or pass data via stash. Anything you put into stash is available in the view.

$c->stash->{qr_url} = $your_generated_url;

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use the QRCode View for Catalyst:

> [Catalyst::View::GD::Barcode::QRcode](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst%3a%3aView%3a%3aGD%3a%3aBarcode%3a%3aQRcode)

That way, the QRCode image will be generated automatically from the data, and no images will have to be stored on your server, taking up space.
That's what I do actually and it's very convenient :)